# is it corrent that using a meaningless leading zero to encode positive ASN.1 INTEGER?

Tags: asn.1

Are these encodings same in ASN.1 INTEGER type?

encoding decimal 10

02 01 0A
02 02 00 0A
02 03 00 00 0A
...

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using BER.  The BER encoding for an INTEGER uses the smallest possible number of octets.  The second and third encodings would be incorrect.

See X.690 8.3

Comment: While this is quite correct, I think it's worth adding that e.g. 020200FF _is_ a correct encoding (decimal 255) i.e. the leading zero is not meaningless when it's needed for a 0 sign-bit. Conversely, 0201FF encodes the decimal value -1.